# Limiting the number of threads Compojure spawns

Tags: heroku, clojure, jetty, compojure

I'm running compojure on Heroku. They have a limit of a 100 threads per process. So when I go over that limit, I get: *java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread.*
Compojure is using the jetty ring adapter. Is there away of configuring the the server to only accept a hundred threads to the servlet at a time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution comes from Chris Perkins over at the [compojure google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/compojure/miJlyihsLNM).

```
(run-jetty app {:configurator #(.setThreadPool % (QueuedThreadPool. 5))})
```

This initializes a QueuedThreadPool (with a concurrent limit of five threads) to the jetty instance, before it starts.